# Where is '_DataLoaderIter' in pytorch 1.3.1?

Tags: python, pytorch

When I use `pytorch 1.3.1` with `python3.7.4`, like this

```py
import torch

from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _DataLoaderIter
```

Here is an errer : `cannot import name '_DataLoaderIter' from 'torch.utils.data.dataloader'`

How should I solve that?

Should I uninstall 1.3.1?

I found `_DataLoaderIter` is in `dataloader.pyi` :

```py
class _DataLoaderIter:
    def __init__(self, loader: DataLoader) -> None:...
    def __len__(self) -> int: ...
    def __iter__(self) -> _DataLoaderIter: ...
    def __next__(self) -> Any: ...
```

But I can't find it in `dataloader.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_DataLoaderIter` does not exist any more. This [code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/v1.1.0/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py) is the latest one that contains `_DataLoaderIter`. You can use `_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter` or `_MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter`. I don't think the .pyi file you mentioned is in version 1.3.1.